# Add ViewController using addChildViewController causing slow performance(100% CPU)

Tags: ios, performance, uiviewcontroller, subview

Need your help over here.
I'm adding ViewController as subviews of another ViewController.

```
addedVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("text_layout") as! TextLayoutCollectionView
self.view.addChildViewController(addedVC)
addedVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
addedVC.view.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0)
self.view.addSubview(addedVC.view)        
addedVC.didMoveToParentViewController(toVC)
```

I'm Adding 4 ViewControllers As Subviews in this same method.

On **IPHONE 4** running **IOS 7** its incredibly slow, about 3-4 seconds before it finish all of them. plus the **CPU** goes up to 100%. 
On IPhone 6+ running IOS 8, seems to work as expected.
I might think that `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` causing it be slow.
**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Look at what thread is using the CPU. Pause the app in the debugger and see what that thread is doing.

Comment: Hey rmaddy , @rmaddy , How can i stop the debugger without setting breakpoint?

Comment: iPhone 4 has a single core CPU. Are your child VCs spinning work off to async threads? On that device they're slowing the main thread.

Comment: Click on the "pause" icon in the debugger.

Comment: @GrahamPerks hey Graham , Hm i'm not sure if i understood exactly what you meant. But the VC's(all of them) holding only CollectionView, im not running anything else from them.

Comment: @rmaddy is it the icon next to the run icon? or am i missing something?

Comment: Try omitting one of the VCs at a time (or commenting out its viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear), to see if there's one in particular causing the slow down.

Comment: @rmaddy k found it lol

Comment: @GrahamPerks will do that now, give me few min to fetch result

Comment: @GrahamPerks I took @rmaddy suggestions , and paused the debugger when the CPU was on 100% , it pasued me on some kind of "system page" under this line : Foundation`-[NSISVariable markedConstraintIsEligibleForIntegralizationAdjustment]:

Comment: @rmaddy notify you as well

Comment: Auto-layout with iPhone 4 can be slow. You might consider an alternate layout method.

Comment: @GrahamPerks im checking if it one of the CollectionViews or else it actually something with AutoLayout in all of them. thats sucks. im autolayout addictive lol

Comment: @GrahamPerks i checked few things and i have found that 1.There is no particularly problem in one of the VC's. 2.It runs smoothly when im only fetching 1, if im trying even 2 is start to get slow. There is something wrong with my method maybe?

Comment: I love auto-layout too :)  Try Instruments and see if that tells you where the time is being spent.

Comment: @GrahamPerks  can you please widen how can i do that? i was never good at debugging lol

Comment: That's much too broad a question. Watch a WWDC video introducing Instruments.